# Добавить проверку на метаполе

Tags: mysql, wordpress

У меня есть запрос к бд который получает среднее значение рейтинга, вот он

```
$rating = $wpdb->get_var( "
            SELECT AVG(cm.meta_value) as avg
            FROM $wpdb->commentmeta as cm
            JOIN $wpdb->comments as c
            ON cm.comment_id = c.comment_ID 
            WHERE c.comment_post_ID IN ($post_id) AND cm.meta_key = 'rating'
        " );
```

Но оно подтягивает рейтинг всех записей, также у меня есть мета поле `comment_email_verify_status`, как можно получить значение рейтинга исключив записи у которых это мета поле не равно единице `comment_email_verify_status != 1`

То есть к запросу нужно добавить условие `если comment_email_verify_status = 1`

Comment: `AND c.comment_email_verify_status = 1`? Странный вопрос...

Comment: @InDevX ты имеешь так? так ошибку выбивает
`$rating = $wpdb->get_var( "
                SELECT AVG(cm.meta_value) as avg
                FROM $wpdb->commentmeta as cm
                JOIN $wpdb->comments as c
                ON cm.comment_id = c.comment_ID
                WHERE c.comment_post_ID IN ($post_id) AND cm.meta_key = 'rating' AND cm.comment_email_verify_status = 1
                
         " );`

Comment: Покажите ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Я не силён в SQL запросах, но для себя с горем пополам делаю. Тебе посоветую вот что.
У тебя либо в условиях объединения JOIN должно быть указано, что ключ метаполя comment_email_verify_status равен 1,
Либо в условиях ниже в WHERE.
Всё через тестирование и знание построения запросов.
Опять же я могу посоветовать тебе сделать запрос через query запрос, с его анализом.
Типа

```
$p_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_barcode',
            'value'   => array(''),
            'compare' => 'IN'            
        )
    )
  );

$results = new WP_Query( $p_args );
echo $results->request;
```

Тут смотрю товары у которых НЕТ метаполя '_barcode' (штрихкод), точнее оно пустое, нет значения 'value'.